# How do I convert a varchar into a negative number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where a column has data such as `($23,324.09)`. If it's `$23,324.09`, then I can convert it to `money`, then a `float`. But the `( )` is causing errors when I try that. Will I have to apply a UDF to that column or is there another way to convert such a value.

NOTE: I don't have control on how the data gets to that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a few `replace()`:

```
declare @col varchar(32) = '($23,324.09)'

select convert(decimal(19,4),replace(replace(replace(replace(@col,'(','-'),',',''),')',''),'$',''))
```

returns: `-23324.0900`

---

Running a simple test, this is runs in about 1/3rd of the time as the `parse()` equivalent.

dbfiddle: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=675f6eb70986bd24880c66a8be4f5cbd

---

Here is a shorter alternative that uses the `money` data type:

```
select convert(money,replace(replace(@col,'(','-'),')',''))
```

dbfiddle: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=31bfc3e1e48b8f863e89bcef9a6ffddc

Comment: if i was to put this in a UDF, would that cause a massive performance hit when dealing with a dataset of 20000 rows (or more)?

Comment: @DaBest 
A scalar udf will drop performance of pretty much anything, an in-line table valued function should be okay though.

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function.aspx)

Comment: @DaBest I added a shorter version that uses the `money` data type.

Answer (score 8):

You could also use `PARSE` or `TRY_PARSE`

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('($23,324.09)' AS MONEY USING 'en-US')
```

Returns

```
-23324.09
```

Comment: I missed the `sql-server-2012` tag; +1